# How to Write A Typed Action Without Parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

A Github issue suggests that we can use `TypedAction.defineWithoutPayload`for this purpose but I couldn't find any relevant examples on how to do so.

I use this for login when an accessToken is being stored in the payload. If the token is present, the user gets access to private pages.

```
export const login = (token: string) => typedAction("LOGIN", token);
```

Now, on the logout button, I am trying to implement an action that removes the stored value in the payload. In this case, there will be no parameters for dispatching the action. So how can I write the typedAction?

If I use:

```
export const logout = () => typedAction("LOGOUT");
```

I start getting an error on my payload of my reducer that property doesn't exist on type logout.

Here's my reducer:

```
export const tokenReducer = (
  state: IState['token'] = null,
  { type, payload }: AppAction,
): typeof state => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'LOGIN':
      return payload;
      case 'LOGOUT':
        return null;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-brook-kntkm?file=/src/store/actions/login.ts:50-118

Email: c@c.com
Password: check

Edit:

```
export interface IState {
    token: string | null;
  }
```

```
const initialState: IState = {
  token: null
};
```

Error on action.payload if I use `state: typeof initialState` or `state = initialState`as per IDE's suggestion:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IState'.ts(2322)
```

If I try `state: initialState`then obviously:

```
'initialState' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof initialState'?ts(2749)
``
```

Comment: In your code sandbox, it looks like you already have `typedAction` handling no payload actions; is that not working? Are you getting compiler errors doing something like `export const logout = () => typedAction("LOGOUT");`? Since the action is unchanging and parameterless, you could even just have it as a constant instead of an action creator.

Comment: Actually, that line works but then I start getting an error in the tokenReducer on payload that ```Property 'payload' does not exist on type '{ type: "LOGOUT"; } | { type: "LOGIN"; payload: string; }'.ts(2339)``` @Jacob

Comment: Does changing the single-arity overload to `export function typedAction<T extends string>(type: T): { type: T, payload: void };` work? Fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-wescoff-qf4h7?file=/src/store/actions/action-creators.ts

Comment: Nope, it still gives the same error, along with other errors like 'expected 1 argument but got 2' @Jacob

Comment: If `initialState` is of type `IState`, why not use the type `IState` instead of doing a `typeof`? If you're trying to get the type of the token variable, use `const tokenReducerInitialState: IState['token'] = null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have your `typedAction` function defined works fine:

```
export function typedAction<T extends string>(type: T): { type: T };
export function typedAction<T extends string, P extends any>(
  type: T,
  payload: P
): { type: T; payload: P };
export function typedAction(type: string, payload?: any) {
  return { type, payload };
}
```

The problem you're having is because of the destructuring of the action in your reducer parameters:

```
export const tokenReducer = (
  state: IState["token"] = null,
  { type, payload }: AppAction
): typeof state => {
  // ...
};
```

One of the difficulties with destructuring and TypeScript is that once you do that, the typing of the variables become independent from each other. Destructuring the action into `{ payload, type }` makes a `type: 'LOGIN' | 'LOGOUT'` and `payload: string | undefined` variable. Even if you later refine the value of `type`, like  in your switch statement, `payload` still has the type `string | undefined`; TypeScript will not automatically refine the type of `payload` in the case block after `type` is refined; their typings are completely independent.

So a somewhat ugly hack you can use is to not destructure:

```
export const tokenReducer = (
  state: IState['token'] = null,
  action: AppAction,
): typeof state => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN':
      return action.payload;
    case 'LOGOUT':
      return null;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This works because in your switch statement, it's able to refine the `action: AppAction` type into the more specific login or logout types, so `action.payload` now is strongly tied to the payload type specific to one of those actions.

Here's an alternative pattern for redux actions I use that you might find more convenient [at my fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-wescoff-qf4h7) that lets you enjoy the power of mapped types to define reducers with less boilerplate. First, you must define a type with the type/payload mappings and define some types deriving from that:

```
export type ActionPayloads = {
  LOGIN: string;
  LOGOUT: void;
};

export type ActionType = keyof ActionPayloads;

export type Action<T extends ActionType> = {
  type: T;
  payload: ActionPayloads[T];
};
```

Your action creators can now be defined in terms of that map:

```
export function typedAction<T extends ActionType>(
  type: T,
  payload: ActionPayloads[T]
) {
  return { type, payload };
}
```

Next, you can define a helper function for creating a strongly-typed reducer:

```
type ReducerMethods<State> = {
  [K in ActionType]?: (state: State, payload: ActionPayloads[K]) => State
};

type Reducer<State> = (state: State, action: AppAction) => State;

function reducer<State>(
  initialState: State,
  methods: ReducerMethods<State>
): Reducer<State> {
  return (state: State = initialState, action: AppAction) => {
    const handler: any = methods[action.type];
    return handler ? handler(state, action.payload) : state;
  };
}
```

(I haven't found a good workaround for that ugly `: any` cast, but at least we know logically that the typing is sound from the outside).

Now you can define your reducers thusly with nice implicit typing for your action handlers:

```
type TokenState = string | null;

export const tokenReducer = reducer<TokenState>(null, {
  LOGIN: (state, token) => token, // `token` is implicitly typed as `string`
  LOGOUT: () => null              // TS knows that the payload is `undefined`
});
```

Comment: Before your answer, I was planning to add ```const initialState: IState = {
  token: null
};``` in the beginning and change ```state: IState["token"] = null```to ```state: initialState``` but it gave an error. Could you suggest a fix for it?

Comment: It depends: how is `IState` defined, and what's the error?

Comment: I added it in the qs