# Overload Typescript arrow function without causing error Duplicate identifier and Function implementation is missing or not immediately following

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, eslint

We use the following code to enable compile check and IntelliSense for our redux reducers:

It is in a `.ts` file and not `.tsx` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576880/3850405)

```
export function typedAction<T extends string>(type: T): { type: T };
export function typedAction<T extends string, P extends any>(
    type: T,
    payload: P
): { type: T; payload: P };

export function typedAction(type: string, payload?: any) {
    return { type, payload };
}
```

This means that our reducers knows what Actions are available:

[image]

Sources:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/set-up-a-typescript-react-redux-project-35d65f14b869

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61276522/3850405

If the below functions are removed no check is done:

```
export function typedAction<T extends string>(type: T): { type: T };
export function typedAction<T extends string, P extends any>(
    type: T,
    payload: P
): { type: T; payload: P };
```

The project recently decided to prefer arrow functions instead of function declarations.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-style

Our eslint config looks like this:

```
"plugins": [
  "prefer-arrow"
],
"rules": {
  "prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions": [
    "error",
    {
      "disallowPrototype": true,
      "singleReturnOnly": false,
      "classPropertiesAllowed": false
    }
  ],
  "prefer-arrow-callback": [
    "error",
    { "allowNamedFunctions": true }
  ],
  "func-style": [
    "error",
    "expression",
    { "allowArrowFunctions": true }
  ]
}
```

This meant that we got the following linting errors:

```
7:8   error    Expected a function expression                              func-style
7:8   error    Use const or class constructors instead of named functions  prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions
```

If the `typedAction` function is converted to an arrow function the following errors are received:

```
export const typedAction = (type: string, payload?: any) => {
    return { type, payload };
}
```

> TS2300 (TS) Duplicate identifier 'typedAction'.
>
> TS2391 (TS) Function implementation is missing or not immediately
> following the declaration.

To be able to continue it is solved like this but a more permanent solution would be preferable:

```
export function typedAction<T extends string>(type: T): { type: T };
export function typedAction<T extends string, P extends any>(
    type: T,
    payload: P
): { type: T; payload: P };

// eslint-disable-next-line func-style, prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions
export function typedAction(type: string, payload?: any) {
    return { type, payload };
}
```

Comment: The rule is inappropriate. Named functions are appropriate for overloads.